# import poly fill in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Working on my first TypeScript project and I am using the fetch api but I need to use a poly fill for the other browsers out there. I would like to use Whatwg-fetch from Github and I have installed the module with NPM and I have the typings file from Definitely Typed. 
When the code in compiled fetch poly fill will not be included and I am not sure how to add it as any time I import Typescript errors.

I am using Grunt, Browserify, TypeScript and React.

I have tried to import with

`import {fetch} from 'whatwg-fetch';`
and
`import fetch = require('whatwg-fetch');`

The definitions are in my main tsd.d.ts file that is included on the page.
Thanks for any help or directions.

Comment: Did you include the definition file in your ts file ?

Comment: Could you show some of your code so we can see how you're importing it?

Comment: What configuration would you expect to make the polyfill file be available in the browser? Is it bundled with other JavaScript that is being loaded via a `script` tag?

Comment: I would like it to be bundled with the rest of the script and keep it out of a browser script tag. This is a front end app but uses node for NPM installs.

Comment: I can't speak for browserify but with requirejs it would look like this: `import 'whatwg-fetch';`. This tells the typescript compiler which type definition to load. Afterwards you need to tell your module loader that whatwg-fetch has to be linked to fetch. With requirejs this would be done with `require.config({paths:{'whatwg-fetch': 'bower_components/fetch/fetch'}});`. I am not sure but I think browserify may have some similar approach...

Comment: Thanks Devlux, I will give that a try and report back.